# How can my Parse.com app send an email using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com (JavaScript SDK), and I want users to be able to send an email from my app.  Basically, they create a page using the app, and then I need to allow them to enter a list of email addresses; the app will then send each address a link to the page they've created.

I can find anything in the documentation which tells me how to send the email, though.  I can take the list of email addresses and generate the email, I just can't figure out how to send it.

Is this possible with Parse?

Answer (score 30):

Parse Cloud Code Modules now support sending email through a number of Cloud Mail Providers:

- [MailGun](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-modules-mailgun)
- [Mandrill](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-modules-mandrill)
- [SendGrid](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-modules-sendgrid)

Comment: which one is the best? :)

Comment: But parse has its own library for sending email. The way they send emails when verify email is turned "on". Isnt there any way to access it?

Answer (score 8):

I created a simple iOS example here, using Mandrill, and Parse Cloud Code
http://www.stlplace.com/2013/11/24/send-email-via-cloud-code-in-parse/

Comment: Thanks for the write up. Saved me some time in my Android implementation. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Someone might find useful example using Mailgun, iOS and Parse Cloud.

I decided to went with Mailgun as Mandril currently had only 4k free mails.

Please note that you had to have access to your domain in order to setup 'TXT' and 'CNAME' records prove Mailgun you are the owner of the domain.

Cloud code:

```
// Use Parse.Cloud.define to define as many cloud functions as you want.
// For example:
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
  response.success("Hello world!");
});

Parse.Cloud.define("mailSend", function(request, response) {

    var Mailgun = require('mailgun');
    Mailgun.initialize('DOMAIN_NAME', 'API_KEY');

    Mailgun.sendEmail({
      to: request.params.target,
      from: request.params.originator,
      subject: request.params.subject,
      text: request.params.text
    }, {
      success: function(httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse);
        response.success("Email sent!");
      },
      error: function(httpResponse) {
        console.error(httpResponse);
        response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
      }
    });

});
```

And now somewhere in your ObjC project:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"mailSend"
                   withParameters:@{
                                    @"target": @"target@mail.com",
                                    @"originator": @"from@mail.com",
                                    @"subject": @"Hey There",
                                    @"text": @"This is your iOS originated mail"
                                    }
                            block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error){

                                NSLog(@"error %@", error);
                                NSLog(@"result %@", result);

                            }];
```

Comment: How the hell do you add TXT and CNAME records? and where?

Comment: You add them inside your hosting provider admin panel. You cannot use this without already purchased/obtained hosting.

Comment: @hris.to Thanks for your response, please how can i use parse cloud function to send just a mail using SendGrid...although, I have actually been able to use it to do both email verification and password reset, but I will like to send just emails using the SendGrid as well, any pointer will really be appreciated. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the android version for @uudaddy's answer

```
public void sendMail(View view) {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("text", "Sample mail body");
    params.put("subject", "Test Parse Push");
    params.put("fromEmail", "someone@example.com");
    params.put("fromName", "Source User");
    params.put("toEmail", "other@example.com");
    params.put("toName", "Target user");
    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendMail", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void done(Object response, ParseException exc) {
            Log.e("cloud code example", "response: " + response);
        }
    });
}
```

Server side JS Code(main.js) Parse Cloud

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendMail", function(request, response) {
var Mandrill = require('mandrill');
Mandrill.initialize('12AkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxrZEg');

Mandrill.sendEmail({
message: {
text: request.params.text,
subject: request.params.subject,
from_email: request.params.fromEmail,
from_name: request.params.fromName,
to: [
{
email: request.params.toEmail,
name: request.params.toName
}
]
},
async: true
},{
success: function(httpResponse) {
console.log(httpResponse);
response.success("Email sent!");
},
error: function(httpResponse) {
console.error(httpResponse);
response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
}
});
});
```

Comment: I am getting the response as null

Comment: You should follow @uudaddy's answer to setup the server rest all is downslide from there.

Comment: @sector11 i want to send email from parse it self. Should i need to do anycode in my backend server or without that it is possible? I just want to code in Android platform to send email nothing else because i do not have other server to handle it.

Comment: Yes read this post clearly with comments and u'll be through... :)

Comment: @sector11 can i send file as attachments?

Answer (score 4):

There is no native method to do this. your best bet is to wait until Parse's Cloud Code supports 3rd-party HTTP requests. I made a quick mockup of how you could accomplish this using IronWorker + Ruby to send the email, but you could certainly use other languages:

http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4506888

Comment: stop voting for my answer. the one below should be the accepted answer.